# Automorphism in Cryptography

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

I read a research paper in which the writer again and again writes about norm preserving automorphism such as
$\left \| \phi(a)  \right \|$ =$\left \|  a\right \|$

and determinant preserving automorphism
$det(\phi (x))=det(x)$

I know what an automorphism is in mathematical sense - an isomorphism from G to G itself.

My question is basically:

What does automorphism indicate in cryptography, particularly in plaintext and ciphertext context. Is it a mapping from plaintext to ciphertext? If so, then why not other type of mapping such as isomorphism, endomorphism etc?

What does determinant indicate in cryptography (plaintext and ciphertext)?

I am actually new to cryptography when I read mathematical terms in cryptography I want to interlink whether these mathematical functions provide security, performance to ciphertext.

Comment: If you are "new to cryptography", maybe you should study a good introductory textbook instead of research papers... What is this paper you are reading, anyway?

Comment: I read Cryptography and Network Security by William Stalling , but automorphism is not covered in this book. Can you tell me a cryptography book which build bridge between mathmatical functions and cryptographic paramaters. By the way link is here http://webpages.uncc.edu/yonwang/papers/octonionAlgebra.pdf @fkraiem

Comment: I think you are in WAY over your head with this paper. For example, when the author writes $\det(x) = \det(\phi(x))$ on page 26, $\phi$ is an automorphism of a Jordan algebra over an octonion ring over a finite field.

Comment: Unless the paper explicitly states that, automorphisms are automorphism and determinants are determinants. If you know what they are, you're good. Your problem to understand the paper may come from other points of the paper (for instance, knowing what a Jordan algebra is and what types of automorphisms it has).